# Is there an alternative to pandas group by rank, in order to avoid the error raised?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rank

I am using group by and rank in my dataframe

```
df["rank"] = df.groupby("category")["score"].rank("dense", ascending=False)
```

However it raises an error as follows:

```
TypeError: rank() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

ValueError: No axis named dense for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute '_aggregate_item_by_item'
```

When I use groupby only it works, however as soon as I add the rank() method it raises above errors.
How can I resolve it? Or if there's an alternative then please let me know.

Comment: Works fine on my side

Comment: `.rank(method="dense", ascending=False)` ?